# R corrplot for 3 arrays of numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following generates 3 arrays from some data frames.

```
Ga = data.matrix(GDP_per_capita_FINALE)
Ia = data.matrix(Internet_usage_finale)
Ma = data.matrix(Mobile_cellular_subscriptions_per_100_people_)

w_GDP = Ga[6,][2:21]
w_internet = Ia[6,][2:21]
w_mobile = Ma[6,][2:21]
```

`print(w_GDP)` returns
`[1]  8169.163  8222.646  8296.169  8435.812  8698.593  8927.916  9204.324  9484.938  9542.370 9269.275  9553.185  9738.992  9867.455 10012.005 10178.372 10349.993 10497.649 10721.484 10920.123 11059.488` and it's about the same for the other two lists

I want to plot a correlation plot between the 3 lists, it should be, and I am expecting, a `3x3` matrix consisting of `cor(c(w_mobile), c(w_GDP))=0.9657749` ,
`cor(c(w_internet), c(w_GDP))=0.9837412`,
`cor(c(w_mobile), c(w_internet))=0.9751028` , and the correlation of 1 between each list with themselves.

What I tried is to make the matrix
`mat = matrix(c(w_GDP, w_mobile, w_internet), nrow=3)` then perform

```
temp = cor(mat)
ggcorrplot(temp, 
       hc.order = TRUE, 
       type = "lower",
       lab = TRUE)
```

But this returns the `20x20`plot

[image]

Which is not what I am looking for, I need the `3x3` plot involving the variables I mentioned above (`cor(c(w_mobile), c(w_GDP))`, and the rest), Anyone know what I should do ?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you share your data to reproduce the issue that you are facing. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the matrix should be created columnwise meaning `w_GDP` should be column 1 and so on. An easy way would be to just put the vectors in a dataframe. Try :

```
dat = data.frame(w_GDP, w_internet,w_mobile)
temp = cor(dat)
ggcorrplot::ggcorrplot(temp, hc.order = TRUE, type = "lower", lab = TRUE)
```